# How to Get Enum GetName By Passing Jquery data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I just want to return a name through C# Enum GetName by passing int value from jquery.How can I do this?I've tried following code.

```
                        success: function (data) {
                        $("#CourseStatics").empty();
                        $.each(data, function (i) {
                            var optionhtml = '<tr><td>' + data[i].CourseCode + '</td> <td>'
                                + data[i].CourseName + '</td><td>'
                                + @Enum.GetName(typeof(AllEnums.Semester), data[i].SemesterId)  + '</td><td>'
                                + data[i].TeacherName + '</td></tr>';
                            $("#CourseStatics").append(optionhtml);
                        });
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass your client-side variable to server-side code that way. 
But you can define object in your javascript code which you can use to covert int representation to name.

For example:

```
var map = {};
@foreach (var i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(AllEnums.Semester)))
{
   @:map['id_@((int)i)'] = '@i';            
}
```

and your code will look like:

```
                    success: function (data) {
                    $("#CourseStatics").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (i) {
                        var optionhtml = '<tr><td>' + data[i].CourseCode + '</td> <td>'
                            + data[i].CourseName + '</td><td>'
                            + map['id_' + data[i].SemesterId]  + '</td><td>'
                            + data[i].TeacherName + '</td></tr>';
                        $("#CourseStatics").append(optionhtml);
                    });
                }
```